# How do I gradually go from one material to another?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to put lips on my character, but as you can see, there is an abrupt line between the lip material and the skin material. It looks super fake. How do I smoothen out the transition between kips and skin? I'm using cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would normally handle something like by using one material across the entire face (or, if it's for a game, one material for the entire character) and paint into the texture the details like skin transitioning into lipstick, etc.
You can use Blender's Texture Paint mode to achieve this, but your object will need to first be UV unwrapped.