# feathered selection of a plane

Tags: selection-tools

Is there a way to feather a selection within one plane in order to have 2 different variables of a procedural texture blend into each other? I can't seem to avoid the hard edge in between the 2 procedurals.[image]

Comment: I suggest adding images to illustrate your question. At the minute it is a little unclear.

Comment: Have you tried vertex color paint? you might be able to paint black in one area, white in another and then blur the edge to get a smooth transition and use that as a mask through the Attribute node.

Comment: How do you blur the edge? I have 2 distinct areas now.

Comment: You can't "feather" geometry selections, use a mask in the material instead, like a procedural based or image texture

Comment: I'm with Duarte on this one, I would add a texture to the mesh instead. If you apply this texture for a temporary time to just paint directly on your mesh, you can use texture paint's brushes to achieve your desired effect quite easily. You can use the standard  F Tex Draw Brush to make your major selection, then use the F Soften brush to feather the hard edges as desired. Remember that you have a tool shelf on the left to where you can control the amount of influence with a high degree of control during this process. Then save this image and use it as your Mix factor.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Similar question, but the other question (and answer) is about an implementation in Blender Internal, not Cycles.

Comment: Hum right, missed that detail, vote retracted. This may be of interest http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74995/assigned-material-has-jagged-edges also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67614/how-do-i-gradually-go-from-one-material-to-another/67637#67637 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials